# My Minecraft Spigot Plugin Not Reporting Back

Tags: java, minecraft

I am pretty new to coding java and I have done a few tutorials, which have been great but i don't know why it isn't working in-game. I have tried everything such as changing it and looking at so many different forums. There are two classes for the events(Join and Leave Event) and the main class. I have made sure to check for importing them and errors none for me to see from where I have looked. If anyone can help it would be a blessing.

**Code: - Main class:**

```
package me.JimmyClown.FirstPlugin;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class MainClass extends JavaPlugin {
    
@Override 
   
public void onEnable() {

        System.out.println("It works!");
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerJoin(), this);
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PlayerLeave(), this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        
    }       
}

**Code for the Join-Class:**

package me.JimmyClown.FirstPlugin;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

public class PlayerJoin implements Listener{
    
@EventHandler
    
void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {
        
Player player = e.getPlayer();
        
e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.BLUE + "Welcome back to the server!" + player.getDisplayName());
    }   
}
```

```
**Code for Leave Class:**
package me.JimmyClown.FirstPlugin;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;

public class PlayerLeave implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    void onPlayerLeave(PlayerQuitEvent e) {
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        e.setQuitMessage(ChatColor.DARK_BLUE + "Awwww, We hope we see you soon" + player.getDisplayName());
    }   
}
```

**The plugin.yml:**

```
name: FirstProject
version: 1.0
main: me.JimmyClown.FirstPlugin.MainClass
authors: JimmyTheClown
description: This is my first plugin.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the access modifier of the event methods to public.

```
public void onPlayerLeave(PlayerQuitEvent e) { }

public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e) { }
```